# Select from table & Variable

Tags: mysql, variables

I need to pull some data from multiple tables depending on a user id and each table is appended dynamically as it is created with user_config_ followed by the user ID

so in this case it would be user_config_134207

I will then have to use this to join to the main database which I am ok with once I know how to achieve this.

The query I have so far is:

```
SELECT max(data)
  from user_config_134207
 where object in (22340) 
   and data not in ('None')
 group 
    by object
```

I need to be able to replace 134207 with a variable if that makes sense?

Comment: Stored procedure with dynamic SQL is the only option. Or build the query text on the client. PS. Storing the values for separate user in separate table is wrong and errorneous database structure abd bad practice.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor schema design

Comment: I'm curious to see how the table `user_config_134207` structure look like. Can you post it?

Comment: Unfortunately I only have permission to run queries from a front end web page so cannot see the structure.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you should be able to run `SHOW CREATE TABLE user_config_134207`. Try it

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on restricted access, I guess you can try prepared statement. Consider this:

```
/*setting variables as NULL*/
SET @sql = NULL;
SET @val = NULL;

/*setting @val variables with ID value*/
SELECT ID INTO @val FROM users WHERE ID=134207;

/*for checking @val value only. can remove in final query*/
SELECT @val;

/*constructing query and set into @sql*/
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT MAX(DATA) FROM user_config_',@val,' WHERE object IN (22340) AND DATA NOT IN ("None") GROUP BY object'); 
    
/*for checking @sql value only. can remove in final query*/
SELECT @sql;

/*prepare, execute then deallocate statement*/
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=113cd4971fecd7b189a2570474ff9899)